# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\lib\security\cacerts (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from the screenshots, you are working on *jdk1.8.0_**111*** directory.
You are trying to read `cacerts` from *jdk1.8.0_**221*** directory, that is supposing to do not exists (`FileNotFoundException` is raised).